# In the next sentence does she really care or is she pretending to care?

Tags: translation, meaning

Context:

A girl is monologuing. She's talking to another girl. She had previously said what she desires is her happiness. After that she monologues:

> 違うんだよ、アリス。私はね、そうやって、自分を誤魔化してるんだよ。

I'm well aware that the sentence she said before means something like: You're wrong, Alice. I'm only saying that to make myself look better.

This is what I'm not sure about:

> あなたのことを気遣ってると思いこむことで、逃げてるんだよ。

I'm just running away from it all by pretending/through caring about you like this.

She really cares or she makes it seem she cares?

Comment: Can you post more context? Who is speaking, who is あなた、and who is "she"? In what kind of situation are they talking?

Comment: A girl is monologuing. She's talking to another girl. She had previously said what she desires is her happiness. After that she monologues: 違うんだよ、アリス。私はね、そうやって、自分を誤魔化してるんだよ。after that she monologues again (the sentence I'm asking about). I'm well aware that the sentence she said before means something like: You're wrong, Alice. I'm only saying that to make myself look better. But I'm asking about the next sentence (the one I in my question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 違うんだよ、アリス。私はね、そうやって、**自分**を誤魔化してるんだよ。

I don't know what you meant by "make myself look better", but I think it means the "monologuing girl" is fooling herself.

> あなたのことを気遣ってると思いこむ**ことで**、逃げてるんだよ。

Here, 「あなたのことを気遣ってると思いこむ」 is the **means** of running away (like you said), but I don't think 「思いこむ」 itself is pretending, but rather "imagining something".

So yes, I think that she makes it seem that she cares, but only in the sense of fooling herself, not Alice. She even goes all the way to explain it to her.

Comment: It is all monologue. She would never tell it to Alice. Lisa had confessed to Alice's loved one knowing she loved him and that he loved her. Lisa was the only one who knew but he stole the boy even so. The monologue is like this (these are just thoughts,they don't actually talk to each other): Lisa: 違うよ。 Alice: いい女で、いい友達で、どうしてそんな残酷な位置にいるんだよ？Lisa: 違うんだよ、アリス。私はね、そうやって、自分を誤魔化してるんだよ。 Alice: これじゃあたし、前にも後ろにも行けない。。Lisa: あなたのことを気遣ってると思いこむことで、逃げてるんだよ。Alice: 一歩も進めない。。

Comment: Knowing this how would you translate those 2 sentences from my question?

Comment: @天照天照 Well, in that case Lisa might not be so innocent but the sentences still mean the same. Lisa is fooling herself into thinking that she's worrying about Alice and that way running away from everything.

Comment: Nice. Last thing, could you give me your literal translation of both sentences? Just to make sure I understood everything right.

Comment: 1. You're wrong, Alice. I am, you see, like that, fooling myself. 2. By imagining that I am worrying about you, I am running away from everything.

Comment: Nice Thank you XD So you don't think (in the second sentence) that she's saying "By making you imagine I care about you" but "By imagining that I am worrying about you"? The difference is quite big in terms of meaning.

Comment: Couldn't the second sentence be "By making you imagine that I am worrying about you, I am running away from everything?"

Comment: @天照天照 I think to make the sentence mean that Lisa causes Alice (or somebody else in general) to be under some impression, the causative form should be used (i.e. 思い込ま**せる**ことで) but not sure how natural that would sound

Comment: I see, so it is Alice who's imagining it. Btw, what's your japanese level? Basically, how sure are you of your answer taking into account your japanese knowledge?

Comment: @天照天照 I'm pretty sure about the meaning of 思い込む here. I've never taken any JLPT or stuff like that but I started studying a bit over 2 years back and I've been pretty immersed for about an year now. The situation itself can have a lot of meanings that I'm missing because I can only see this part of it as text and also because I'm not native. If you feel that this interpretation doesn't fit the context, you can add some context to the question and wait if somebody else sees another meaning than what I did

Comment: No need, I was just curious. Thanks for everything XD